# How to copy folder structure but exclude certain files in Windows?

Tags: total-commander, copy

I have a parent folder with hundreds of subfolders containing mainly video files.
I would like to replicate its structure 1:1 on another drive, but without copying video files which account for 99% of folder space.
Parent folder size is 3TB so copying it and then deleting all video files is not viable solution, it will be too time consuming.

I am using Windows 7

Is it possible in Total Commander?

Comment: If you can identify the files you do not want to copy, you can accomplish this with Sync Back Pro (2brightsparks). I use this and exclude files not needing to to copied / sync'd.

Comment: robocopy (built in windows) should be able to do it. The check `robocopy /?` to check all the flags, but I think you can use /XF and you can use with *.mov for example (to exclude all .mov file. If your video files have a particular extension - you can exclude them .. haven't tested it myself so thats why I don't put this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To copy directory structure without copying any files using Total Commander, enter `|*.*` into 'Only files of this type' field. This will exclude all files.

Comment: Press F5 (Copy) to bring up the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

## Using robocopy to duplicate the directory structure

1. Open the location of the parent folder in file explorer.
2. Hold shift and right click on empty space in the folder and click "Open command window here".

[image]

3. Type `robocopy "parent folder" "G:\parent folder" /E /XF *` into the command window.
   **Note: Replace `parent folder` with the actual name of your folder
   and replace `G:` with your actual destination drive letter.**
   Press enter to execute the copy.

Command Explanation:

The command usage is `robocopy source destination` /E means copy subdirectories, including empty ones, and /XF means exclude files. We have indicated the wild card character `*` for exclude files in order to exclude all files and only reproduce the directory structure.

*Thanks to [@Darius](https://superuser.com/questions/1654994/how-to-copy-folder-structure-but-exclude-certain-files-in-windows#comment2532617_1654994) for the suggestion.*

Answer (score 0):

https://totalcmd.net/plugring/CopyTree.html CopyTree 1.3.0.328

> Packer plugin for copying files with folder structure:
>
> - copies/moves folder trees from branch view/search result
> - 'choose number of levels to copy' dialog that allows observing relative paths for all cases
> - allows setting up include/exclude masks for files to be proccessed
> - allows displaying choose dialog once or if Win key is down or every time
> - multi-threading support (background operations in TC 7.55 and later)
> - allows copying directory timestamps
> - reports if some files weren't processed
> - full Unicode support
>
> Plugin allows you to keep directory structure when you copy/move files
> from branch view (Ctrl+[Shift+]B by default, or "Branch View" command)
> or search results panel ('Feed to listbox' button in search results
> dialog). TC copies files in theese modes w/o keeping directory
> structure, into single directory (TC 8.50+ allow keeping directory
> structure relative to current directory in case of branch view).